# PyCUDA when using multiple blocks to deal with matrix operation, why does matrix size have to be divisible by the block size?

Tags: python, matrix, gpu, pycuda

I am learning GPU programming on PyCUDA. I am a bit confused by the calculation of matrix operation on the blocks. Like the example below, I want to redo the calculation

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
c = a[:,np.newaxis] - a
```

which should be

```
c = [[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5],
     [1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4],
     [2,1,0,-1,-2,-3],
     [3,2,1,0,-1,-2]]
```

on GPU.

Follow the code below, if I allocate the same size for matrix and the block. Everything works fine. But to test computation in multiple blocks, I allocated 4 to the block size, things got wrong. I have checked the blockDim for each entry in output c. It shows some of the entries have 0 blockDim but they should be all 4.

```
array([[4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
   [0., 0., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
   [0., 0., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
   [0., 0., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
   [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
   [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]], dtype=float32)
```

and the threadIdx.x shows wrong number at the same position.

```
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 2., 3., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 2., 3., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 2., 3., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

This is very strange.

Repeatable code is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from pycuda import compiler, gpuarray, tools
import pycuda.driver as drv

# -- initialize the device
import pycuda.autoinit

kernel_code_template = """
__global__ void com_t(float *a, float *c)
{

// 2D Thread ID 
int tx = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; // Compute row index
int ty = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; // Compute column index

// Pvalue is used to store the element of the matrix
// that is computed by the thread
float Pvalue = 0;

// Each thread loads one row of M and one column of N, 
//   to produce one element of P.
float Aelement = blockDim.x;
float Belement = 0;
Pvalue = Aelement - Belement;

// Write the matrix to device memory;
// each thread writes one element
c[ty * %(MATRIX_SIZE)s + tx] = Pvalue;
}
"""

MATRIX_SIZE = 6
BLOCK_SIZE = 6
start = drv.Event()
end = drv.Event()

# # create a random vector
a_cpu = np.array([i for i in range(MATRIX_SIZE)]).astype(np.float32)

# compute reference on the CPU to verify GPU computation
start.record() # start timing
start.synchronize()
c_cpu = a_cpu[:,np.newaxis] - a_cpu
end.record() # end timing
# calculate the run length
end.synchronize()
secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
print("CPU time:")
print("%fs" % (secs))

# transfer host (CPU) memory to device (GPU) memory
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a_cpu)

# create empty gpu array for the result (C = A * B)
c_gpu = gpuarray.empty((MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE), np.float32)

# get the kernel code from the template
# by specifying the constant MATRIX_SIZE
kernel_code = kernel_code_template % {
    'MATRIX_SIZE': MATRIX_SIZE
    }

# compile the kernel code
mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code)

# get the kernel function from the compiled module
matrixmul = mod.get_function("com_t")

start.record() # start timing

# set grid size
if MATRIX_SIZE%BLOCK_SIZE != 0:
    grid=(MATRIX_SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE+1,MATRIX_SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE+1,1)
else:
    grid=(MATRIX_SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE,MATRIX_SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE,1)

# call the kernel on the card
matrixmul(
    # inputs
    a_gpu,
    # output
    c_gpu,
    grid = grid,
    # (only one) block of MATRIX_SIZE x MATRIX_SIZE threads
    block = (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, 1),
    )
end.record() # end timing
end.synchronize()
secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
print("GPU time:")
print("%fs" % (secs))


# print the results
print("-" * 80)
print("Matrix A (GPU):")
print(a_gpu.get())

print("-" * 80)
print("Matrix C (GPU):")
print(c_gpu.get())

print("-" * 80)
print("CPU-GPU difference:")
print(c_cpu - c_gpu.get())

np.allclose(c_cpu, c_gpu.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The evaluation of matrix c should be put in a constrain like

```
if((ty <matrixsize) && (tx < matrixsize))
```

Otherwise, the over requested threads will be invoked and squeeze out the right entry of c.